# Ansible: Using item(with_items) in changed_when statement

Tags: ansible

I'm using `with_items` iterator to execute command: `brew services stop {{ item }}`.

To handle errors I'd like to use `changed_when` and use `item` value in it.

```
command: brew services stop {{ item }}
  register: stop_services
  changed_when:
   - "'Error: Service `{{ item }}` is not started.' not in stop_services.stderr"
  with_items:
   - memcached
   - kafka
```

If service is not started, I get following error

> failed: [127.0.0.1] (item=memcached) => {"changed": false, "cmd": ["brew", "services", "stop", "memcached"], "delta": "0:00:00.464519", "end": "2016-12-29 18:02:37.795973", "failed": true, "item": "memcached", "rc": 1, "start": "2016-12-29 18:02:37.331454", "stderr": "Error: Service `memcached` is not started.", "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": [], "warnings": []}

But `changed_when` statement is ignored.

Is it possible to inject `item` into `changed_when` statement?

Ansible version: 2.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a failing task in the first place. The `command` module will report failure if the return code from the command was other than zero (in your case `"rc": 1`) and that's why your `changed_when` condition is not taken into consideration.

Add the following to [prevent failing](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_error_handling.html#controlling-what-defines-failure):

```
failed_when: false
```

Comment: You can also use `ignore_errors: yes`, which will tell you if something failed, but will ignore it.